# Best way to get data into Colab Notebook

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, colab, aws, cloud-computing

I am working concurrently with multiple very large datasets (10s-100s of GBs)). I signed up for Colab Pro+ thinking it is the best option. However, I face a significant bottleneck in getting data into Colab.

My options all seem very bad:

1. Downloading from AWS (where the data is located) - very slow.
2. Uploading data to Google Drive and mounting Drive using below code. This is also surprisingly very slow.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

3. Paying for a persistent server. Something like a persistent AWS SageMaker notebook. This is very expensive. With even a mediocre GPU, it comes out to $2k/mo.

What is the best solution here? I am ok with paying for a good option as long as its reasonable. Have any of the numerous MLOps startups developed a good solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Faculty Platform.
I had a good experience with large datasets(10s of GB) with them.

[Faculty Platform](https://faculty.ai/platform/)